# Why is calling two times that API?

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of img elements, each one with an span with an X that I use to delete the specified image. For double check, whenever the user clicks the X I show a modal to get confirmation. The functions that do that are the following:

```
function refresh() {
            $('#deleteImg .btn-primary').click(function () {
                var src = $(this).data('src');
                var elem = $(this).data('elem');
                $.post('/api/deleteimage', {src: src}, function () {
                    elem.remove();
                    $('#deleteImg').modal('hide');
                })
            })
        }


function refreshImages() {
            $('.img-wrap .close').click(function (ev) {
                refresh()
                var src = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('img').attr('src');
                var elem = $(this).closest('.img-wrap');
                $('#deleteImg').modal('show').find('.btn-primary').data('src', src).data('elem', elem);
                refresh();
            })
        }
```

It works well but the deleteimage API is called two times, why is that?

Comment: You're calling `refresh()` twice in `refreshImages()`

Comment: The logic is a little weird here. Why are you assigning click handlers in functions? After the second call to `refreshImages` you will have assigned the same click handler **4** times to `.btn-primary`, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I should call stopPropagation method.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `refresh()`, you bind a click event to `$('#deleteImg .btn-primary')`. This is additive, so if you bind it twice then click once, the click function will be triggered twice. Aaaaand you call `refresh()` twice in `refreshImages()`... Probably not a coincidence :)